# Denwer лег

Tags: denwer, localhost, сервер

После устанавки WebMatrix, не могу зайти на localhost, пишет, что не может найти страницу Error 404. В файле hosts localhost прописан 127.0.0.1

WebMatrix удалил уже, Denwer пару раз переустанавливал - не помогло

в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Так какой там индексный файл по умолчанию? Может его нужно указать в httpd.conf (или что там по умолчанию в денвере)

Comment: индексный файл чего? я несколько раз переустанавливал денвер, стоян все стандартные настройки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это вот этот Денвер: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denwer , то и не удивительно! В Denwer веб-сервер - Apache, а WebMatrix работает только с IIS. Кстати, Денвер (это если тот), желательно устанавливать в режиме "на флешку".

Comment: удалить IIS и установить дннвер на флешку?

Comment: изменил на порт 8080 и заработало    # Listen $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}    #NameVirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}    #< VirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80} >

Comment: Ну правильно! Если там ещё и IIS стоит, то они с Апачем, что в Денвере, и должны были бодаться, если на одном и том же адресе и на одном и том же порту!!! А как порт поменял - вот оно и заработало.